# Logical operators evaluation in javascript

Tags: javascript

Can you explain how works the Comparison Operators in JS:

```
 "a" > "A" // => why true?
  null == undefined; // and here as well?
```

and some others

```
   null >  0;
   null >= 0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are compared by their character codes, ie. their positions in the Unicode table.
`A` is 65, `a` is 97. Therefore `"a" > "A"`.

`==` is a loose comparison. `null == undefined` is a special case, since the [*abstract equality comparison algorithm*](https://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3) explicitly states that `true` should be returned when comparing these two values:

> 2. If *x* is `null` and y is `undefined`, return `true`.
>   3. If *x* is `undefined` and y is `null`, return `true`.

`null > 0` is false, and `null >= 0` is true because `null`, when converted to a number, is zero.

Comment: `null` and `undefined` are not converted when doing `null == undefined`. The abstract equality algorithm explicitly states that `true` should be retuned in that case.

Comment: but: null === 0 will be false?

Comment: @user2754035: You can just type it in the console and find out. But yes, it's `false` since `null` and `0` are of different data types. If you want to know what happens when you compare two values with `===` or `==`, have a look at the specification: https://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3 .

Comment: @Tyblitz Sadly, `+rep` means nothing here :p I already have my +200 for the day. Thanks for the upvote though!

Comment: Are you going to fix the part about `null` and `undefined`?

Comment: @FelixKling I'll be honest, I don't fully understand the details of `==` and type coercion. There's no reason why you can't edit my answer though ;)

Comment: Alright, hope you are OK with that. I'm a little surprised, since usually your answers are spot on, but I'm sure once you looked at the algorithm you'll think "that's easier than I thought" ;) Happy coding!

Comment: @FelixKling Very nicely done, thanks :) And yes, there *are* things I don't know :p